# Variable assignment within function in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to create a pooled connection object with `MongoDB` as per http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html however my code behaves in an unexpected manner.

Needless to say I'm fairly new to Javascript and Node.js... and my intended pool variable (`db`) is `undefined` even though I assigned it within the `.connect` statement. How can the `db` be empty (`undefined`) outside the `MongoClient.connect` statement although it got assigned alright within the statement?

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const connOptions = {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}
const connString  = 'mongodb+srv://Master:mypass@' +
                    'cluster0.vpss6.mongodb.net/' +
                    'sample_analytics?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

var db

MongoClient.connect(connString, connOptions, function(err, database) {

  if (err) throw err
  db = database

  console.log(db) // prints an object

})

console.log(db) // prints undefined :/
```

Comment: The key thing to notice in your results here is that `undefined` is printed *before* the object is printed.  This is because the `connect` function is asynchronous.  It's successfully setting the `db` value, it's just doing so *after* you try to print it outside of that operation.

Comment: I see! Thank you! :)